# PHP Trim function not removing whitespaces

Tags: php, trim

I'm doing some tests with learning purpose. I have a PHP script in which I used some functions to see how they work:

- First I used isset to make sure a var exist
- Then `empty` to make sure if a var has some value
- Finally I used `trim` to remove whitespaces

After some testing I realized that trim function is not working properly.
For example I can still write `whitespaceCHARwhitespace`, then I used `strlen` function and I get a 3 as a result. What's wrong with my script?

Btw I would like to know how acceptable is this form validation I would like to avoid some sqlinjection.

Thanks in advance.

```
<span><?php echo $msg;?></span>
<form method="POST">
    <label for="name" class="white-headers">NAME</label>
    <input type="text" name="name" id="name" class="form-control">
    <label for="last_name" class="white-headers">LAST NAME</label>
    <input type="text" name="last_name" id="last_name" class="form-control">
    <input type="submit" class="btn btn-success" name="submit">
</form>


   $msg="";
  if(isset($_POST["submit"])){
   $name = $_POST["name"];
  $last_name = $_POST["last_name"];
if(!empty(trim($name)) && !empty(trim($last_name))){
    $name_len=strlen($name);
    $last_name_len=strlen($name);
    $msg="<div class='alert alert-success'>
    both fields are set and have some value name =".$name." with ".$name_len." chars and last_name =".$last_name."
    with ".$last_name_len. "chars</div>";
}
else{
    $msg="<div class='alert alert-danger'>
    both fields are set but one or both are empty name =".$name." and last_name =".$last_name."</div>";
}
}
```

Comment: you don't save the trimmed string. you count on the original string

Comment: so I have to do empty first, then
$var = trim($name) etc?

Comment: Please post the exact code you have been using for getting the strlen of 3. It will be easier to determine the error this way. BTW your question about form validation belongs in a separate question.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The only times you're using `trim` there are when you check whether or not there's anything left after you trim the variables:

```
if(!empty(trim($name)) && !empty(trim($last_name))) {
```

That doesn't affect `$name` and `$last_name`.

`trim` returns a string with the whitespace removed, but it doesn't change the value of the variable given as an argument. If you want those to be trimmed for later use in your code, you need to set them to their trimmed values, like `$name = trim($name)`, etc.

In your case, you could probably trim them when you set them from `$_POST` initially.

```
$name = trim($_POST["name"]);
$last_name = trim($_POST["last_name"]);
```

Then you can check if there's anything left more simply:

```
if ($name && $last_name) {
```

`empty` isn't necessary because you know they're set, and zero-length strings evaluate to false.

Comment: so after if(empty()) I need to do something like
$varname=trim($varname) and so on? if so is that the correct order of using the functions?

Comment: trim first (by assigning the result of `trim` to your variables), then check if they're empty second. But like I said in the edit, you don't really have to use `empty()` for that.

Answer (score -1):

As specified in the [documentation](http://php.net/manual/en/function.trim.php), `trim` only removes whitespaces at the beginning or at the end of a string. Whitespaces in the middle are not affected (using `_` to mark a whitespace):

- `__string` will become `string`
- `string__` will become `string`
- `s_t_r_i_n_g` will remain `s_t_r_i_n_g`

Plus, as pointed in [Don't Panic's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/49806822/3110448), you are checking the strings *after* the `trim`, not its return value.

About the form validation: if you want to clean your inputs before using them in your application, simply trimming them isn't enough. There are many ways to sanitize inputs, every framework offers some options, but since you specifically spoke of sqlinjections, my suggestion is to start by reading PHP's [mysqli.real_escape_string](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli.real-escape-string.php)

Comment: I haven't voted on your answer myself, but I'd suggest that one reason someone may have downvoted it is your suggestion to prevent SQL injection by escaping strings rather than using prepared statements.

Comment: @Don'tPanic I think it was downvoted because it doesn't address the question nor answer the problem which is the fact that the string was not trimmed. Reason is because trim was only used to check and not set. it's already well answered by... *scrolled up*... lol you.